# Prevent ffmpeg from overwriting existing output file

Tags: ffmpeg

I have created a small batch script for a thumbnail gallery with ffmpeg. When I try to process several input files, the outputted file gets overwritten every time, output1.png gets renewed, instead of creating output1.png, output2.png, output3.png etc. How can I increment the counter?

```
for %%A IN (*.mp4) DO ffmpeg  -i "%%A"  -vf "mpdecimate,yadif,select=not(mod(n\,30)),scale=384:-1,tile=5x50" -frames:v 1 "C:\Users\Rambo\Desktop\Videos\newfiles\output%%d.png"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How can I increment the counter?

Use the following batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set count=0
for %%A IN (*.mp4) DO (
  ffmpeg  -i "%%A"  -vf "mpdecimate,yadif,select=not(mod(n\,30)),scale=384:-1,tile=5x50" -frames:v 1 "C:\Users\Rambo\Desktop\Videos\newfiles\output!count!.png"
  set /a count+=1
  )
endlocal
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)